# Multiple background sockets in an iphone voip app

Tags: iphone, sockets, voip

Is it possible to mark more than one socket to keep them open in background in an iphone voip app?

Comment: What did you find out? I'm running into similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), only one socket should be configured for VoIP usage. You are free to configure multiple sockets for VoIP usage, but only one socket will be managed by the operating system when your application is suspended.